# Strange expression parsing behavior

Tags: f#

In this code:

```
let f(a,b,c) = a * b + c - (d())
let g(a,b,c) = a * b + c -(d())
```

`f` is `(int*int*int) -> int`, and `g` is `(int*int*(int*int)) -> int`.

Removing the brackets around `d()` in `g` causes the "Successive arguments should be separated by spaces or tupled" error.

What's going on?

Comment: `c -d()` means `d() |> (~-) |> c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@bytebuster is quite correct in his comment, but to put it into layman's terms ;-] one is parsed as the binary subtraction operator and the other is parsed as the unary negation operator – you're simply fighting operator precedence here.

Comment: I was just thinking it wouldn't worth a full answer :) and, since it hardly helps any further visitors, the Q will be deleted soon.

Comment: @bytebuster : I actually typed this as a comment and at the last second cut/pasted it into an answer thinking, "what the hell?" :-]

Comment: @bytebuster How does this not help further visitors? It's a curious technicality.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka To me, this question is about a typo, likewise `fx` instead of `f x`. Obviously, there will be an error. Considering operators involved, type inference may produce misleading error messages.

Comment: @bytebuster That's absurd. Most languages, including related ones like Haskell, will parse `f` and `g` just the same. F# is clearly an exception in that whitespace is significant not just in indentation but also, apparently, in prefix operators.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka : _Most_ languages (though maybe not most _functional_ languages) treat `-N` in isolation very differently than `- N`.

Comment: @ildjarn I beg to differ. I just tried `5 -3` in [JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/HJWeU/), [Python](http://codepad.org/MYKN01th), [C#, VB.NET, F#](http://www.pexforfun.com/), [Haskell](http://codepad.org/SKKWG8yo), [Ruby](http://codepad.org/qQOpwQoC), [C](http://codepad.org/9T414JUq), [D](http://codepad.org/wy7BwxFt), [Lua](http://codepad.org/ZtJAVdjH), [PHP](http://codepad.org/w43EfB1M), [Perl](http://codepad.org/BvmVT46N), hell even F#'s parent language [OCaml](http://codepad.org/vpgpSKH7). The *only* language that outputs anything other than `2` is F#.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka : You apparently missed the `in isolation` part. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn I don't know what you mean by that more than what I'd already presented, but it's completely irrelevant. Try `5 -3` in any context in F# -- bracketed, as a function argument, without brackets in REPL, whatever -- it'll puke.

Comment: If by isolation you mean e.g. `- 3` instead of `5 -3`, all those languages output `-3` -- including, ironically, F#.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka : "*all those languages output `-3` -- including, ironically, F#.*" Indeed... ;-]

Comment: `5 -3` is a bit different to `a -b`. Probably, because `5` can't be inferred as a function, hence no chance for `5(-3)`. Contrary to `a(-b)`.

Comment: @bytebuster The parser still appears to treat literals and identifiers the same here, only producing an error during type inference in the case of the former. `let f a b = a -b` in Haskell is still `Num a => a -> a -> a` unless the `-b` is bracketed, whereas in F#, it's `(int -> 'a) -> int -> 'a`. Using whitespace as an indication of fixity is a common convention, but it's not a rule in any other language that I've tried. It's surprising behavior by any measure, and it's not a "typo" on my part.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka Your arguments look convincing. They may become a part of another question, *"What are the reasons why F# treats whitespaces in a different manner?"* Perhaps, someone from the F# core team would provide with an answer. As we see, they haven't attempted answering *this* question, that's why I think *this* question is not very good (own research is not shown, too localized, and whatever).

Comment: @bytebuster Why would the F# team answer a question that I haven't asked, especially when someone else already answered my question? Why does it even matter whether or not they answer? All I wanted to know was, again, "what's going on". Now that I know, I have a rough idea of *why* it's going on: unlike Haskell, F# is imperative, and unlike ML uses indentation, and unlike Python allows multi-line expressions, and so there's no way to distinguish between a two-line expression joined by an infix, and two statements, the second of which begins with an operator that can be either prefix or infix.

Comment: @bytebuster The question is also not localized at all. The example I gave uses a very general form that can arise in anyone's code. An infix operator with a whitespace in front and no whitespace after isn't uncommon, and that indeed can be a very simple typo that yields very confusing and seemingly unrelated type errors. You only happened to have thought initially that it was localized because you thought it was just a typo that *I'd* make, when in fact, as I've demonstrated, it's a well-established notation that F# has deviated from -- and so it simply isn't a matter of being a single typo.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka "you thought it was just a typo that *I'd* make" - correct. Otherwise an irrelevant error message haven't been mentioned, the sample had been simplified (`a`, `b` are irrelevant as well) and something about own research on whitespace character would have been added. :)

Comment: @bytebuster At this point you're accusing the question of being too localized because it isn't the most mathematically general form. It's still probably the most common manifestation of this problem, and so, from a developer's practical standpoint, it's perfectly general, and I'd done the most research that I could have done not knowing what exactly was causing that manifested error. It's the only way anyone could know to ask the question without knowing the answer. You're taking "too localized" to an absurd extreme.